# VSCode cycle through opened files only within its own split window

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have 2 split windows with a few files opened in both of them as shown in the image below. I'm using the shortcut keys (on mac) "cmd+shift+[" or "cmd+shift+]" to cycle through all the opened files ("Open Previous/Next Editor"). However I was wondering if we could lock the "next" opened file that we will cycle to to be within the current split window that we are on?

i.e. Say right now I'm on 'window 2' (the split window on the right according to the image), pressing "cmd+shift+[" would bring the focus to the left split window and onto the "Untitled-4" file, but is there a way to prevent that and make it cycle to "Untitled-5" instead?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found the option to perform what I wanted.

It's the `"View: Open Next/Previous Editor in Group"` command.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, I can use Ctrl+Tab or Ctrl+Shift+Tab to do this.

Answer (score 1):

its actually the default behavior of vscode, it will cycle through opened files on the certain split window only. on the windows you could use `ctrl+tab` to do this